# How can i replace dot with comma in iReport?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

At first this question is needed for iReport.
I have to replace the dot sign with comma. My problem is the type of the field out of our database is BigDecimal und therefore does not exist any replace method. 
So I changed the type to String, but then I got this message:

```
it.businesslogic.ireport.gui.logpane.ProblemItem@820dc5 The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

My code looks like:

```
new String($F{gewicht}.toString()).replace(".",",")
```

What can I do?

Comment: But do you need to format a number? seems like an [x-y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), you use Locale and pattern in jasper report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a textfield pattern:

```
<textField pattern="#,##0.00 €">
```

This will give you the german format. In this case this is for € values but you can skip the € and add more descimals if wanted:

```
<textField pattern="#,####0.0000">
```

Another approach whould be:

`new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00 €", 
   new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.GERMANY)).
     format(Double.parseDouble($F{gewicht}))`

Comment: Thanks, I tried this at first. But it doesn't change anything. @hering

Comment: We use this for double values, so we need to cast it to a double before this will have any effect. Although the variable is a double value we need to cast ist.
`Double.parseDouble($F{gewicht})`

Comment: I have this problem with double to, e.g. 
cust_kost_ges field Type java.lang.Double; 
Text Field Expression Class java.lang.Double; 
Pattern #,##0.00 
and my output is e.g. 120.00 € not 120,00€

Comment: If your dataprovider is JSON I would recommend changing the field type to String and cast it to Double when needed, we encountered a problem when using JSON and a Double field.
What you can also try is `new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00 €", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.GERMANY)).format(Double.parseDouble($F{gewicht}))`

I added this this approach to my answer above.

Comment: You are welcome.
feel free to accept the answer as correct :)

Answer (score 2):

Try entering the following as a text expression:

```
$F{gewicht}.toString().replace(".",",")
```

If this doesn't work, one alternative would be to handle the formatting in your Java layer, e.g.

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(1.2345);
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
String gewicht = df.format(bd);
```

Here I have used the European German locale, where decimal points and commas reverse roles from what they are in the US and some other places.  You probably want to handle both commas and decimal points.

Comment: Nice, even nicer when the example would be `new BigDecimal("1.2345");` (precision 4) as opposed to 1.2345 (no precision determinable by java).

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I tried it, it works, but the error message is the same. To the second sollution: Where can I find the Java layer?
Thanks.

Comment: I am referring to the Java code which generates the Jasper report.

Answer (score 1):

To bypass the problem: The type java.lang.CharSequence cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

You can set a new DecimalFormat like:
new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00 €", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.GERMANY)).format(Double.parseDouble($F{gewicht}))

Thanks @hering